# Error converting Json string to array of objects PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I made a post in a form converting my javascript localstorage to a post request. From there I tried to decode my json string to make an object in PHP.

How my php code looks before I echo it

```
    $cart_items = $_POST['cart_items'];
    $cart_items = json_encode($cart_items);
    $array_test = json_decode($cart_items);
    print_r($array_test);
```

What it returns in browser

```
[{\"id\":83494890,\"title\":\"2020 Hino 358\",\"partType\":\"Bumpers\",\"price\":100,\"stockNumber\":12313131312,\"thumbImg\":\"/jOIY91KhEby8_f.jpg\",\"permalink\":\"/part-description/?part=83494890\",\"maxQuantity\":1,\"requestedQuantity\":\"3\"}
,{\"id\":83493833,\"title\":\"2009 Freightliner 5020080\",\"partType\":\"ABS Modulator Valves\",\"price\":150,\"stockNumber\":\"P-1211111111157\",\"thumbImg\":\"/OOjQbsi6p8kX_f.jpg\",\"permalink\":\"/part-description/?part=83493833\",\"maxQuantity\":1,\"requestedQuantity\":\"1\"}]
```

I know that typically when seeing json data there isn't forward slashes everywhere. I tried to json_decode into an array rather than an object, then make a foreach for each object inside. But I got this error returned "*Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*"

How do I make this json string convert to an array of objects? Thank you

Comment: Could you `var_dump($_POST);` before that and share here what would be coming in on POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$_POST['cart_items']` already contains JSON. So you just need to decode it, not encode it first.

```
$array_test = json_decode($_POST['cart_items'], true);
print_r($array_test);
```

But it's actually encoded twice, that's why it has escaped quotes, so you need to call `json_decode()` twice. But it's missing the double quotes around the whole thing, and the embedded newline is not valid.

The following works:

```
<?php
  $cart_items = '"[{\"id\":83494890,\"title\":\"2020 Hino 358\",\"partType\":\"Bumpers\",\"price\":100,\"stockNumber\":12313131312,\"thumbImg\":\"/jOIY91KhEby8_f.jpg\",\"permalink\":\"/part-description/?part=83494890\",\"maxQuantity\":1,\"requestedQuantity\":\"3\"},{\"id\":83493833,\"title\":\"2009 Freightliner 5020080\",\"partType\":\"ABS Modulator Valves\",\"price\":150,\"stockNumber\":\"P-1211111111157\",\"thumbImg\":\"/OOjQbsi6p8kX_f.jpg\",\"permalink\":\"/part-description/?part=83493833\",\"maxQuantity\":1,\"requestedQuantity\":\"1\"}]"';
  $array_test = json_decode(json_decode($cart_items));
  print_r($array_test);
```

I suggest you find the code that's sending the `cart_item` POST parameter and fix it so it doesn't do all this extra encoding.

Comment: So I did try this at first, but nothing gets printed without the json_encode. However when I print the string without the decode it still has the slashes and looks very similar.

Comment: it's not valid JSON. There needs to be `"` around it, and it can't have a newline in it.

Comment: @IncredibleHat If it were an array of JSON, it would look like `["{\"id\":83494890,...]`

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. I just needed to get the post type, add quotes around it then do a double json_decode. I don't understand what happened. I know this isn't the best code on my part. I think posting the input reformatted it. Thank you for heading me in the right direction!

Comment: @Barmar hmm. Yeah, something aint right with the incoming data. Hopefully OP can figure that out now that they got a better handle on it :D

Comment: Shouldn't the `true` flag be a `false`, or left off? Title is a little confusing but I first read it as wanting a JSON object, not the associative array - although looking again, I'm not 100% sure, @davidb3rn, care to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was having was when I was getting the $_POST[] it was using PHP's "magic quotes" which was giving me improper format for my json. That being said, after disabling this, it removes the slashes.

Comment: Magic quotes has been obsolete for years. You must be using a very old PHP version.